# How to open the mail window in Thunderbird from an extension?

Tags: thunderbird, thunderbird-addon

I'm developing an extension for Thunderbird, and want to open a message, just like a double-click in the inbox folder. I do have the message references (messageID / messageKey). How do I open the dialog?

Answer (score 1):

Found out how it is possible, the MailUtils module provides some nice functions. You need the message header, though, and not the message as e.g. found via Gloda. So you have to convert them first.

So, first import MailUtils:

Components.utils.import("resource:///modules/MailUtils.js");

and then use the functions, e.g. displayMessages or openMessageInNewWindow, as defined here:
http://mxr.mozilla.org/comm-central/source/mail/base/modules/MailUtils.js